# Dejar campos vacios de datatable para insertar

Tags: c#

Como le puedo hacer para que el valor Null o vacío no se convierta en cero.
Tengo esta linea:

```
int T150 = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j]["T150"] is DBNull ? null : dt.Rows[j]["T150"]);
```

y cada vez que la ejecuto me inserta ceros en los campos que deberían ir vacios, ¿como lo puedo hacer para que los campos me los siga dejando vacios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que si lo guardás en una variable int siempre va a ser un número.
En este caso creo que lo mejor sería guardarlo en una variable [Nullable](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/), o sea, T150 podría valer null o un valor numérico.
El código sería así:

```
int? T150 = dt.Rows[j].IsNull("T150") ? null : new int?((int)dt.Rows[j]["T150"]);
```

Si el valor del DataTable no es un int, por ejemplo es un string con un número, deberías hacerlo así:

```
int? T150 = dt.Rows[j].IsNull("T150") ? null : new int?(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j]["T150"]));
```

Después podrías consultar si T150 tiene un valor con la propiedad "T150.HasValue".

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Oye una, pregunta, hice las lineas como pusiste, y me funciono, pero cuando quiero insertar los valores null, me marca como si el campo estuviera vacio y por lo tanto ya no procede a insertar los datos, hay alguna forma de resolver esto, ya busque en otros lados, pero no es muy diferente a esto que me pusiste

Comment: No entiendo, dónde querés insertar los valores?

Comment: es cuando los mando con la instrucción para guardar en sql server

Comment: En ese caso, deberías preguntar si T150.HasValue, en cuyo caso deberías pasarle el valor, en caso contrario deberías pasarle NULL, para que no se guarde valor en ese campo.  Cabe mencionar que el campo debe permitir valores nulos, sino te va a dar error.